# php popen() opts with a space in it?

Tags: php

Hii i have this code :

```
            $handle = popen("php -q nah.php -p=". '$part' . " 2>&1", "r");
            while (!feof($handle))
            {
                 $read = fread($handle, 2096);
                    echo $read;
            }
            pclose($handle);
```

And the the nah.php looks like this:

```
echo "yaya1\n";
$options = getopt("p:");
$part = $options["p"];
echo $part;
print_r($options);
```

The output of this comes out to be:

> yaya1 Array (
>       [p] =>  )

While the $part in the main file has content.
What can be the error in it ?
How can i fix the error ?
Thanks 
And all this is done in php-cli

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.3 ? I need to check because some changes were made to one of the functions you are using in that version.

Comment: Heh, which one is it? 5.3.2 allows you to separate a command-line argument from it's value with an equals sign, as you've done. 5.2.3 doesn't allow that, and would probably give you the output you described. You can run `php --version` on the command-line to check the version.

Comment: To be more specific : 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to replace the line that runs `popen` with this:

```
$handle = popen("php -q nah.php -p=". escapeshellarg($part) . " 2>&1", "r");
```

This uses the `escapeshellarg()` <sup>***[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)***</sup> function in order to wrap the `$part` variable in quotes (and escape any quotes inside it), so that it can be used as a shell argument safely.

The error was that you had `$part` within single quotes, so it was being sent to the shell directly as `$part` instead of the value being replaced by PHP. The shell then tried to look for a *shell* variable called `$part` to replace it with, but since there was none, it simply replaced it with a blank.

This code would also have worked:

```
$handle = popen("php -q nah.php -p=". $part . " 2>&1", "r");
```

However, that would not have wrapped the variable in single quotes, so if there were any spaces in it, only the first word would have been considered the value of argument `p`, all the other ones would have been considered different arguments.

It's generally good practice to use `escapeshellarg()` when sending arguments to a shell command since it takes care of quoting the argument for you.

Comment: Works Thanks :D.
Btw what was the error in it can u please tell me. So in future i can overcome those?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to my explanation of why your previous code wasn't working. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: One good way of debugging this type of thing is to create the shell command inside a variable, as in: `$cmd = "php -q nah.php -p=". '$part' . " 2>&1";`. Then you can output `$cmd` to check that what's being sent to the shell is actually what you wanted to send. In a lot of cases, including your original one, this will show you where the mistake is.